# VLookup across workbooks VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking to create a Vlookup procedure which will look for the account number of this workbook (Daily Shout End) in the Dataset file. It will then return the Connection ID value (Dataset file) into the HET Lead Account column of this workbook.

I've created a VLookup in a loop which conducts the VLookup until the last row. b, c, d & e represent the column letters and numbers which I have used in the VLookup formulas. VLValue represents the Col Index for the VLookup.

When I run this, "Connection ID" (column heading in the dataset wb) is being returned for all cells in the specified range and I can't figure out why. Can anybody see the issue here?

```
Sub HETVLookup()

Dim b As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim d As Range
Dim e As Range
Dim AccNoValue As Integer
Dim AccColumnNumber As Long
Dim AccColumnLetter As String
Dim AccDSColumnNumber As Long
Dim AccDSColumnLetter As String
Dim HETColumnNumber As Long
Dim HETColumnLetter As String
Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim VLValue As Long
Dim VLRes As String

LastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Daily Shout End").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

DatasetFile = Dir(pStr & "Dataset*.xlsx")

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Daily Shout End").Rows(1)
    Set b = .Find("HET Lead Account", LookIn:=xlValues)
    HETMRColumnNumber = b.Column
    'Convert To Column Letter
    HETMRColumnLetter = Split(Cells(1, HETMRColumnNumber).Address, "$")(1)
    If Not b Is Nothing Then
    HETMRColumnNumber = b.Column
End If
End With

'finding the column number and letter for account number in daily shout file
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Daily Shout End").Rows(1)
    Set c = .Find("Account Number", LookIn:=xlValues)
    AccColumnNumber = c.Column
    'Convert To Column Letter
    AccColumnLetter = Split(Cells(1, AccColumnNumber).Address, "$")(1)
    If Not c Is Nothing Then
    AccColumnNumber = c.Column
End If
End With

'finding the column letter and number for HET Lead in the Dataset file (connection ID)
With Workbooks(DatasetFile).Worksheets(1).Rows(1)
    Set d = .Find("Connection ID", LookIn:=xlValues)
        HETColumnNumber = d.Column
    'Convert To Column Letter
    HETColumnLetter = Split(Cells(1, HETColumnNumber).Address, "$")(1)
    If Not d Is Nothing Then
    HETNumberCol = d.Column + 1
End If
End With

With Workbooks(DatasetFile).Worksheets(1).Rows(1)
    Set e = .Find("Account number", LookIn:=xlValues)
        AccDSColumnNumber = e.Column
    'Convert To Column Letter
    AccDSColumnLetter = Split(Cells(1, AccDSColumnNumber).Address, "$")(1)
    If Not e Is Nothing Then
    AccDSNumberCol = e.Column + 1
End If
End With

VLValue = HETColumnNumber - AccDSColumnNumber + 1

For i = 2 To LastRow

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Daily Shout End").Cells(i, HETMRColumnNumber).Value2 = _
Application.VLookup(AccColumnLetter & i, Workbooks("Dataset 20210127.xlsx").Worksheets(1).Range(AccDSColumnLetter _
& ":" & HETColumnLetter), VLValue)

Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: By `AccColumnLetter & i` did you mean to lookup "B2" or the value in `Range("B2")`, for example?

Comment: This is how the formula looks in Excel (and it works on Excel) "=VLOOKUP(D2,'[Dataset 20210127.xlsx]HET DataSet'!$A:$B,2,0)"

Comment: If you're using `Application.Vlookup`, you need `Range(AccColumnLetter & i)` and you should probably be explicit about the `.Value`: `Range(AccColumnLetter & i).Value`.

Comment: Hero! Worked a treat. Thanks BigBen